# PHP KCFinder Session security option

Tags: php, session, ckeditor, kcfinder

I have the following CK editor file manager: https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder
My problem is I have one CMS system and would like to secure the browser.php file. If member who not logged in on the site can open the brwser.php and he/she can delete the uploaded images. I have a login system which checks the  `$_SESSION['userlogin']` is empty or not. So my question is where to add my login session to check if the `$_SESSION['userlogin']` is empty or not? I tried take it to the browser.php, but it is not working:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['userlogin'])) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/login');
}
```

When i try to `var_dump($_SESSION)` it shows me NULL why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KCFinder already has this feature built into it. In your login procedure, you should set a session variable:

```
if($login_successful) {
  $_SESSION['KCFINDER']                 = array();
  $_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled']     = false;    
}
```

KCFinder should be disabled by default, it's this session variable that enables it. Does this solve it?

Comment: Yes thank you. disabled = false was my problem, I had true option.